# Show that a comparison of the two way drugs can be made by means of the statistic $(b-c)^2/{b+c}$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, contingency-tables

> suppose two drugs are administered to each of *n* patients suffering from headaches. The reactions are summarized in the following Table:

```
                             Drug 1
                  Good      Not Good   Total
          Good     a          b         a+b
Drug 2  Not Good   c          d         c+d 
         Total    a+c        b+d         n
```

> Starting from the marginals (a+b) and (a+c), show that a comparison of the two way drugs can be made by means of the  statistic $\frac{(b-c)^2}{b+c}$, which is approximately a $\chi_1^2$.

Please give me some hints so that I can solve this homework. The problem is a large sample problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statistic that has the asymptotic chi square distribution is

(O$_1$-E$_1$)$^2$/E$_1$ + (O$_2$-E$_2$)$^2$/E$_2$+ (O$_3$-E$_3$)$^2$/E$_3$ + (O$_4$-E$_4$)$^2$/E$_4$

where O$_i$ is the observed cell total and E$_i$ is the expected cell total under the null hypothesis that the two drugs have the same probability of working. Find out what O$_i$ and E$_i$ should be in terms of the observed cell frequencies a, b, c and d to get the given test statistic.  The null distribution is asymptotically a central chi-square random variable with degrees of freedom equal to (R-1)(C-1) where R is the number of rows and Cis the number of columns.  In the example R=2 and C=2 so the degrees of freedom equals 1.

Comment: I don't understand what will be $O_i$ and $E_i$ in terms of the observed cell frequencies a, b, c and d.Please help.

Comment: This is a homework problem (even though not tagged as such), so I should give hints rather than answers.  The oberved are the actual cell frequencies a, b, c and d. For the expected frequencies think about if the sample size is a+b for drug 1 and c+d for drug 2 what cell frequencies would be most likely if the null hypothesis is true.

Comment: I was little confused but now I understand .Thank you.